# Adding R output in the same sheet in excel

Tags: r

I've been using the following functions to put my output in R in different sheets but what if I want my outputs to be below each other like my example below

```
data<-loadWorkbook("trial.xls",create=TRUE)
createSheet(data,name="tr1")
writeWorksheet(data,rows,sheet="tr1")
saveWorkbook(data)
```

So I would want my spreadsheet to look like this

```
Values Median STD Length
3       5      6   7
6       7      7   8
Values Median STD Length
4      7      8   1
6       9      0   3
```

thanks guys

Comment: do you want the header to repeat?

Comment: ah...u r right...I dont think I would want the header again

Answer (score 0):

You can set `starRow=` in `writeWorksheet()` to set position in Excel sheet. Here is example where in one sheet I wrote data `iris` and `cars`. With `startRow=(nrow(iris)+2)` I set position just below previous table (+2 is used as first table contains also column names that are not counted by `nrow()`). To remove header for the second table put `header=FALSE` in second `writeWorksheet()` call.

```
library(XLConnect)    
data(iris)
data(cars)
wb<-loadWorkbook("trial.xls",create=TRUE)
createSheet(wb,name="tr1")
writeWorksheet(wb,iris,sheet="tr1")
writeWorksheet(wb,cars,sheet="tr1",startRow=(nrow(iris)+2),header=FALSE)
saveWorkbook(wb)
```

Answer (score 0):

You may also want to have a look at `appendWorksheet`. See `help(appendWorksheet)` for more information.

Example Code:

```
require(XLConnect)
wb = loadWorkbook("test.xlsx", create = TRUE)
createSheet(wb, name = "mtcars")
writeWorksheet(wb, mtcars, sheet = "mtcars")
for(i in 1:5) appendWorksheet(wb, mtcars, sheet = "mtcars", header = FALSE)
saveWorkbook(wb)
```